# How can I replace reflection with guice?

Tags: java, reflection, dependency-injection, guice

I have long used reflection to decouple modules from "handlers".

I have a code base which is architected like this :

```
static enum AnimalHandlers {
  Dog(Dog.class),
  Cat(Cat.class);

  private final Class c; 

  AnimalHandlers(Class class)
  {
    this.c=class;
  } 

  public Class getAnimalHandler()
  {
    return c;
  }
}
```

Then later in my code, I have a method which takes an "Animal" enum as input and uses reflection (that is, it gets the class from the enum and invokes "newInstance") to invoke the necessary handler.

I think the solution would be cleaner with Guice.  How can I get rid of the enum/reflection and simply use guice to "hydrate" my control module with domain specific logic handlers?

Comment: Your example may be over simplified from your real code, but from the way this is structured why not just use `new`? Why use reflection at all?

Comment: Because .... Imagine animals are of different type, and a large list of them are sent to a class that forwards control to different handlers.  You need an if statement which depends on the type of animal being handled (so you need a large if block with several new statements in it, and thus couples th logic of looping through animals to the animals themselves, which leads to an unmaintainable system that can't be extended easily by multiple developers.... And js hard to test.

Comment: To be honest, I think your enum-based solution isn't all that bad. Perhaps there is some readily available pattern for your kind of problem, but I haven't found one amongst the common design patterns. Do you require a new handler each time? If you could make the handler classes stateless you could just have one instance for every enum constant.

Comment: `Dog.class` is the handler class right?  And `Dog` is the name of a `AnimalHandlers` that matches the name of an `Animal` enum?  How is the `Animal` enum tied in here?  And the reason why you have to do a `newInstance` is because the handlers aren't reentrant or something or there is not a 1 to 1 mapping between animal and handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could well use a `MapBinder<AnimalEnum, AnimalHandler>`, and define a binding for each possible `AnimalEnum` value.

Comment: Hmm... I realized that this does not fully answer the question : because I want to REPLACE the enum - I dont need it - I just need a list of classes, and I want guice to do the ugly reflection work for me.   is that possible/>

Comment: Well I'm not sure I perfectly understand what you want. You could as well use a MultiBinder<AnimalHandler> but how do you know which handler to use, and based on what? You definitely need to clarify your question with a concrete use case, or better, ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

I think that there must be a better pattern here.  I'm a little confused as to just how the `Animal` enum interfaces with the handler but I'll make some general suggestions and maybe one will stick.

- I assume that there is no way to define the handlers in the `Animal` enum and you want to decouple the classes.  Fine.
- Could the the handlers register themselves with `Animal.setHandler(...)`?  Then you could just call `Animal.Dog.getHandler()` to get Dog's handler.
- I agree with @jfpoilpret that some sort of `AnimalHandlerMapper` would also be better. I assume there a common interface is possible, even if it just a marker interface.

Code:

```
private static Map<Animal, AnimalHandler> handlerMap
    = new HashMap<Animal, AnimalHandler>();
static {
    Dog dog = new Dog();
    handlerMap.put(Animal.Dog, dog);
    // we use the same handler twice here
    handlerMap.put(Animal.Wolf, dog);
    handlerMap.put(Animal.Cat, new Cat());
    // do a Animal.values loop at the end to verify that everyone has a handler
}

public static AnimalHandler getHandler(Animal animal) {
    return handlerMap.get(animal);
}
```

- If for some reason you can't use the handler instances then I would do the same thing but with handler factories.  So you've call `handlerMap.get(animal).create(animal)` or some such.  This would be much cleaner than using reflection.
- I'm not sure how Guice compares to Spring but if this was spring I would instantiate the handler beans and they would register with the `AnimalHandlerMapper` to completely decouple it.

Hope this helps.